Are my ocean currents acceptable?
I really don't know if this is the right place to post this.
After about 6+ or so months of trial and error (and like, hours re-watching the videos Artifexian made on them), I've managed to come to these ocean currents for my alternate earth. And i was wondering if these are passable and acceptable (while this world isn't really supposed to be realistic, more so leaning towards fantasy?) I'd at least want the world to be somewhat passable)
The map represents the currents during Northern Hemisphere summer by the way.
Personally I don't see a lot issues, maybe the mess of currents in the pacific but that's cause of those islands which idk if they could actually affect currents like that (do large islands and archipelagos with shallow seas affect ocean currents like that?)
Maybe the southern gyres as well, idk why but they look off but idk.
If anyone is willing to take a quick glance and give me some advice and criticism on this, feel free!


Is there just less water on the planet or is it supposed to be bound up, i.e. larger ice caps? That effects climate and the basic thermo-saline current drivers.

The southern gyres look off for a simple reason: one goes clockwise and the other counterclockwise.
Gyres formation is caused by Coriolis force, and in the same hemisphere that force can change of intensity, not of direction!
East from Japan in your map you also two currents crossing each other undisturbed: that also looks very off.

Thank you for pointing out the counterclockwise current in the south under Australia, wouldn't have found out without that. Also the "intersecting currents" is just poor placement honestly, The warm current that goes up to Japan is supposed to come down to those islands as a cold current and the Oyashio current is supposed is supposed to connect with the warm current at 45°N, but they do end up looking like they cross eachothers paths. ill try to make them look like they arent.
